# Haroopad not starting and prompt of "NVCtrl extension does not exist" message

Tags: gnome, software-installation, gpu, markdown

I installed Haroopad on my Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 system. I had to change some symbolic links in order to make it work. However after I've closed it, I tried to run it, but I'm getting this message:

```
`[3964:0201/150344:INFO:gpu_info_collector_x11.cc(80)] NVCtrl extension does not exist.
```

My graphics come from the Intel Chipset of my laptop's motherboard.

- What can I do in order to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a problem with libffmpegsumo.so

See [this.](https://github.com/rhiokim/haroopad/issues/261) A replacement appears to be available on a link on [this](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/1423) page.

rename the old libffmpegsumo.so to libffmpegsumo.so.bak,  place the replacement libffmpegsumo.so in the same location as the original.